# Javascript document write button inside function used by another function not working

Tags: javascript

Just for fun I'm trying to make a small game with javascript, I'm pretty new to programming so this was more of a test of what i could do.

I have the following inside of a function that happens when i press a button, this does correctly make the new button appear but It won't reconize the function below it when pressing this new button

```
function clickStart(){
document.write("<input type='button' value='attack!' onClick='clickAttack();' /");
```

The other Function looks like this

```
function clickAttack(){
    if(heroHealth >= 0 && monsterHealth >= 0){
```

This function is right after closing the first one.

The Console gives me the following

```
ReferenceError: clickAttack is not defined
```

I'm not sure how i could fix this.

Help will be appriciated

Comment: aren't you missing a closing bracket > for input html element ?

Comment: Where is `clickAttack` defined?

Comment: Where have you defined these functions. If in a .js file then check if .js file is loaded.

Comment: check if your click attack doesn't have any missing braces or syntax errors

Comment: document.write ... so 20th century, sorry, look at better alternatives - here are some terms to search for - innerHTML, insertAdjacentHTML, appendChild, document.createElement - sure there's more that you'll need, but document.write should be expunged from the earth

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the many reasons not to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers: They require that any functions you use in them be *globals*. Globals are Bad Things™. Your functions apparently aren't globals, which is a Good Thing™.

Separately, `document.write` has essentially no place in web development in 2016 (or 2006). Instead, use the DOM. One advantage of doing that in your case is that it means `clickAttack` no longer has to be a global:

```
function clickStart() {
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.type = "button";
   input.value = "attack!";
   input.addEventListener("click", clickAttack, false);
   document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes this works, thanks! I realized document.write was not really used anymore but it was the only thing i knew to write to the page but using HTML DOM is alot nicer

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use jquery like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.myButton' , clickAttack);                   
});


function clickStart(){
        $( "body" ).append( $( "<input type='button' value='attack!' class='myButton'/>"));
        }
function clickAttack(){
        alert("hello");
        }



<input type='button' value='add!' onClick='clickStart();' />
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello I recommend you to use jQuery library. The code will be simple for you.

My solution for you is [here in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr47ychh/1/)

I used self [invoke function](https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/) where init function register [event listener](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) `.on()` click and this call attack function

If you have any questions feel free to contact me.

The js code:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

  function attack() {
    $('#logger').append('Attacked!<br>');
  };

  function init() {
        $('#attackBtn').on('click', function() {
        attack();
    });
  };

  init();
})();
```

Comment: please comment why -1

Comment: FWIW, I see two probable reasons: 1. This doesn't answer the question of why the OP's code doesn't work. 2. ["Use jQuery" is not a valid answer to non-jQuery questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question) It is, at most, a comment.

Comment: jQuery its just suggestion ... he wrote he is beginner so i give him suggestion. Second why his function not working is solved there. The code told him that function attack should be included because there is Reference Error. So this error told him that function is not included into code...

Comment: The question states quite clearly that the `clickAttack` function *is* in the code: *"This function is right after closing the first one."*